# OnSelectedIndexChange want to load a function and get data into label without refreshing page

Tags: asp.net

I am loading a function on selected index change for getting data in label, but i dont want to reload complete page. So far I have done this

```
    <asp:TemplateColumn>
            <headertemplate>
                <label>Article</label>
            </headertemplate>
            <itemtemplate> 
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpArticle" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged = "DrpArticle_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems = "true"> </asp:DropDownList> 
                <asp:Label ID="LblStock" runat="server" Text="..." ForeColor="#000066"></asp:Label>
            </itemtemplate>
   </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Use UpdatePanel or an Ajax solution. UpdatePanel might be the easiest solution.

Comment: already tried but giving error on run time.

Comment: may be im missing something

Comment: can you help with how to use update panel or ajax for this.

Comment: you can take help from https://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: it is giving me an error as i am doing this inside datagrid.